# How to wrap text around plots in R Markdown?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Currently the default for R Markdown in R is to have one line of text in line with the plot but this looks very awkward and I would like to save space by having the text wrap around the plot (plot aligned left, with text wrapping on the right).

Comment: someone reposted your q and got an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551312/wrap-text-around-plots-in-markdown