# Wrap text around plots in Markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am reasking this question:
[How to wrap text around plots in R Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652012/how-to-wrap-text-around-plots-in-r-markdown):

'Currently the default for R Markdown in R is to have one line of text in line with the plot but this looks very awkward and I would like to save space by having the text wrap around the plot (plot aligned left, with text wrapping on the right).'

Comment: dont repost questions, start a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use CSS styling to position the elements however you want. However there can be some difficulties and it does require some tweaking.  Here is a simple example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Ian Wesley"
date: "April 21, 2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown
<div style= "float:right;position: relative; top: -80px;">
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
</div>

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Yields:

[image]

Comment: In a slight revision that includes a png, this plots the image over the text, obscuring the text.

Comment: what is .myPlot? reference or object?

Comment: You know I think it is a typo... So I corrected it.  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 24):

It appears there is an easier way now by adding two arguments to the r chunk:

`out.width= "65%", out.extra='style="float:right; padding:10px"'`

This scales the plot to 65% of the page width and lets text float on the left side with a distance of 10px.

Comment: Do you put the text before or after the chunk?

Comment: `{r chunkname, echo=FALSE, out.width= "65%", out.extra='style="float:right; padding:10px"'}`

It's in the chunk header.

Comment: For me, the text following the code chunk begins to wrap around the figure. Text prior to the figure code chunk does not wrap. Also, for me this solution did not work with `kable` tables.

Comment: I get an error saying that the style is unknown.

Comment: I tried this solution and its giving me the following error : `! Package keyval Error: style undefined.`